# Apply for a position with a company via a recruiter. Can I apply for a different position with the same company by myself?

Tags: hiring-process, recruitment, applications

Via a recruiter I applied for a position to a certain company (earlier this week).

Today, I have seen that there is another position in the same company and department for which I would like to apply. I don't know if this can be seen badly by the HR (or whoever else looks at the applications), or it is just a non-standard way to act.

Any advice or comment?

Further info:
I do not know if the recruiter was aware of this 'new' position and he thought that my skill set matches better the first.

Comment: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/27808/is-it-ok-to-bypass-the-recruiter-when-i-dont-hear-from-him is this related at all?

Answer (score 5):

That depends entirely on the contract between the recruiter and the company, about the best you can do is contact the company and ask. (if you ask the recruiter they'll almost certainly say you need to go through them)

Answer (score 2):

Most companies will disqualify you from consideration if you are presented twice.  Since you have already been presented to the company they probably have an obligation to use that agency if it wants to bring you on.

Generally if you try to present yourself, or have another company present you the company will simply remove you from consideration in order to avoid a potential legal entanglement.  Most companies have a policy of 6 months to a year lapse between being presented by a company(or yourself) and being presented by another agent(including as your own agent).