# Headhunter works for client company; client company has other position open

Tags: recruitment

A recruiter has an agreement to find applicants for a company. I, the job applicant, called the recruiter telling them that I am the best person for the job, and hand him a resume. The recruiter sends my resume to the company

I search the company's database for open jobs in the hope that their opening is public, but it is not. This ends my hope of contacting the company directly about the job, because then I would be stepping on recruiters toes. However, the company has another job opening available that is public. These job openings are in the same department.

Do I the company directly about this job, or do I delegate the work to  to the recruiter for this public job opening? Keep in mind that job candidates that apply through personal connections are generally more likely to earn the job than those that applied simply through a job application.

THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE. This concerns another job opening by the same company. Would it be okay to bypass the recruiter because the recruiter is not aware that this job opening is available?

Comment: wait wait, really strange, I is you or it's someone shortened name ?

Comment: I, C, and R are placeholders.

Comment: please use another letter, I is a strange one to chose ;)

Comment: @GautierC Fixed. Re-read.

Comment: @Chad No: This is a different job.

Comment: @JossieCalderon - Answers still apply good luck with that attitude though.

Comment: Perhaps you could edit your question to explain why you feel it is ok to by bypass the recruiter here?

Comment: @Chad: See edit

Comment: Are you sure the recruiter does not know about the job?  have you asked the recruiter?

Comment: @Chad I left a voicemail 15 minutes ago to call me and I explained in the voicemail about this new position. The recruiter has not called me back yet.

Comment: so this should be a dup of : http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/33027/apply-for-a-position-with-a-company-via-a-recruiter-can-i-apply-for-a-different

Comment: @Chad: Dutifully agreed.

Answer (score 2):

**Let the recruiter handle your case.**

Why ? Just because if you apply and that news falls into R's hands, he will think you don't trust him, and will end up closing all the possibilities to work for the company.

Just wait for him to do his job, and that will be fine, no need to answer the job application when you have a better entry, and to risk something you don't want to see happening.