Is it appropriate to reach out to executives and/or engineers at a company to express interest in a position?
I recently applied to a job posting on LinkedIn. The company in question is a relatively new (but reputable) startup that seems to have just received their first round of funding. The team comprises a small group of around 10-15 people, and as far as I can tell all are either executives or engineers. I'm unable to identify a recruiter, and no hiring manager is listed.
I feel that my skills and background are a very strong match for the position— I meet precisely all of the desired and preferred qualifications, and have a fair bit of other relevant experience in spite of being a recent graduate. I noticed, however, that within just a few minutes of the requisition being posted over 100 people had clicked "apply".
I would like to reach out to someone at the company to express my interest in hopes of boosting my odds of being invited for an interview. I'm unable to find an e-mail address for anyone, so I am planning to attempt to connect via LinkedIn. I have previously done this with recruiters and hiring managers, however I have never reached out to an executive or engineer at a company directly. I have two questions:

Who, if anyone, would be most appropriate to reach out to? I am applying for a software engineering position. I'm only able to find LinkedIn profiles for the CEO, the President, and a couple of engineers whose work is distinct from what it seems that I would be engaged in.
How, if at all, should I approach messaging someone at the company who is not a recruiter or similar? When reaching out to recruiters, I typically write something along the lines of "Hi, my name is X, I'm interested in position Y, here is my relevant experience...". Does this hold when reaching out to someone who is not a recruiter?


Possible duplicate https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/166953/is-it-a-good-idea-to-contact-the-hiring-manager-of-a-company-thats-going-throug

@AdamBurke Is LinkedIn the same thing as a recruiting agency though? Can't any company advertise jobs there and handle the recruitment themselves? Because that would be a different scenario than your proposed duplicate.

@roganjosh For context, this is an entry-level software engineering position in support of a relatively niche field of applied physics work, making use of a very niche set of software frameworks. I have spent a few years involved in precisely this sort of work in an academic environment, and am one of fewer than 250 people that have contributed to the aforementioned open-source frameworks. There are perhaps a handful of groups (academic or industry) working in this niche and, while many people could do this work, very few have experience with precisely these problems and software.

@roganjosh Presumably because so few people work in this, the job requirements are along the lines of "you have a technical degree and experience writing software" plus "it would be nice if you have worked in X niche with Y niche software, but we know that no one does so we plan to train you". I'm sure that the vast majority of applicants meet or exceed those qualifications, but would be surprised if any have experience with or have perhaps even heard of X and Y.

Please don't do this!
Firstly it's not going to work - you're trying to speed-run networking and that isn't how it works. You aren't going to establish any meaningful rapport in the space of one "you don't know me, interview pls" interaction.
Secondly it's annoying as all hell, I've been the recipient of this sort of attempt before, both when I was involved and not involved in the hiring process. When I was I always assumed it was a pathetic attempt to "stand out" or "show initiative" or and at the very least neatly demonstrated "can't follow the hiring process" and unless they were a truly astounding candidate in every other respect they went straight to the bottom of the list. When not I always just binned it unless I happened to know that the person doing the hiring was desperate for candidates, then I would forward it on with "this person sent this to me, no idea who they are think they're lost" type message.
It would be different if you already had a connection to someone (even if that person wasn't directly responsible for hiring), but that's just garden variety networking.

I feel like this is highly based on the recipient / company. It could go either way.

I don't know, with very small companies I feel like this is not a bad idea. I've done this several times when there was no direct job opening I could have applied to and people were usually receptive. When there is a job opening you can directly apply to it might be a bad idea in some cases but it's not so cut and dry.

@Peter I'd agree that where there isn't an actual opening to apply to then it can change things, but the scenario the OP describes explicitly has one (that they have applied to) and they're attempting to give their application a boost and that is what I'm advising against.

As someone who handles hiring software engineers at a startup I, and my team, would recommend the opposite. Shoot your shot but not through LinkedIn. Email someone at the company directly. At my company, it actually does differentiate yourself from the pack and will usually ensure an interview spot if your resume looks solid. We like the initiative since we're in a bit of a niche space. We've hired at least 2 good engineers this way out of a team of 8-10 currently. Make sure to include why you're interested. In my experience these candidates tend to be better than what recruiters find anyway.

@motosubatsu Still, I think your are drawing too much of this from your own opinion. In other lines of work (consulting, banking etc.), hitting up employees on LinkedIn for coffee chats with the possibility of ending up with a referral is super common.

I would also recommend reaching out. At previous jobs there would be hundreds of applicants that all fall somewhere around meeting all of the required qualifications. It wasn't always feasible to review every application in depth, let alone interview everyone. Reaching out to someone at the company shows you are more interested in the position than someone who is just clicking "Apply" on any job. Now, if you didn't meet the qualifications, I would agree with this answer. Having people reach out who needed visa sponsorship, lived out of range, or didn't have the requisite skills was annoying.

@Peter I'd prefer to say that I'm drawing from my experience - I've been involved in all aspects of hiring (both sides) and in companies ranging from tiny startup, all the way to 1000+ employee enterprises in a variety of sectors. I've never seen what the OP poses help, AlwaysConfused's comment is the first time I've even heard a hiring manager say they've responded positively specifically to that, I doubt his experience is unique but personally I also doubt it's common either. [1/2]

[2/2] Coffee chats are a thing in some sectors but IME tend to be part of a more traditional networking strategy rather than as a specific attempt to sales pitch an existing application. If the OP were to approach for such a chat in a "I've applied and would like to get to know more about your company" as opposed to a "here's my CV that you already have, I'm awesome, you should interview me" I think that's better, so long as they able to take a "no" and not be be pushy.

@TomPridham the answer box is below. If you have a different answer use it.

Just a general anecdotal note: In my life, I have had a few "don't call us, we call you!" experiences, most of them not even workplace related. The conclusion I can draw in retrospect is that the opposite is true. It's almost like a hidden message, the first hurdle to take: If you sit still, you will not be called.

So, I have been on both sides of this. It can go well or it can sour things, and in so many dumb ways it can come down to how the day of the person who reads your email is going.
I have had great emails that lead me to note something positive on a candidate and in other cases something rubbed me the wrong way and it colored how I evaluated the candidate if I later interviewed them.
Having been on the other side, sending letters, I have had good enough luck to get interviews, and in other case had no response.
I think one thing to note when you write a letter to a small start up is that they are often mission and product driven and so you should lead in with how you identify with their product and what its trying to solve.
As for who, I would usually recommend the VP Engineering or the CTO if they have one or the other.
Good Luck.


Usually at this size of the company, when someone receives an email/call where they are the wrong recipient, this person will forward the email/call to the correct destination. Probably your email will be forwarded to the correct person even if your guess is wrong.
I propose that you follow your gut to choose the person because each company and title are unique. Maybe it is not the CEO that recruits, it is more developer X that is not even the one with the most experience but worked closely at a previous company with the founder.

You are not vouched or solicited for your approach, so you may perceive something a little more better than a spam and they are probably receiving already a lot of offers from recruiters pushing candidates, consultant firms, supplier, etc. Be ready to differentiate yourself from others and your message should be the shortest possible without diminishing the transmitted idea:

having an online demo/gallery of some stuff you have done in the past;
an interesting power slide explaining why you are the best candidate.


Do not trust LinkedIn with "100 people already applied". It means nothing, I often apply to a position with +100 people, sometime I get a call in the following hour, sometime I get a call two weeks after, sometime never.



There's a difference between when there is an explicit job ad out as in this case,  and just reaching out to a company showing your interest.
Bothering people about an advertised job by not going through the official channel is just going to rub them the wrong way. If I'm the manager who's put the initial vetting of candidates in the hands of HR or a recruitment agency, it's either because I'm too busy to detail manage this recruitment, or because I think the recruiters will do a better job at vetting out interesting candidates.
The "too busy" scenario is particularly delicate - if you reach out to a manager who have outsourced the recruitment simply because they don't have the time to go through one hundred candidates in person, they will not appreciate if ten or so of those candidates call them in person, particularly not before the initial vetting. So that might reflect negatively on you.
But when there is no explicit job ad out: just generally expressing your interest in the company and telling you what you are good at could be well-received. Largely depending on the person and the company- and country culture. Depending on such culture, contacting the manager directly and expressing interest could either be taken as a positive show of initiative or it could be a faux pas. But in that situation you aren't also part of some on-going recruitment procedure so what have you got to lose?
If I'm the manager and get surprisingly poked out of the blue by people expressing interest in the company, who have done some initial company-candidate matching of their own before reaching out and who got the relevant expertise: I don't mind. Even if there's no position available right now, I might ask for their CV leave a note about them for later. I've actually hired someone later after a situation just like that.

also: if the manager is security aware, they might consider this a social engineering attack (either against the company or the candidate) and be particularly on their toes...depending on what the caller says.^^

Do you like getting unsolicited phone calls and spam emails?
If no, then why on Earth are you even posting this question?
Put yourself in your target's shoes. They almost certainly aren't involved in hiring, and they almost certainly have work to finish that does not involve talking to you. At best you can expect them to hang up on you or block your email, at worst your name gets out as a problem into the industry and you end up blacklisted.
And all that is ignoring the fact that you're essentially attempting to jump the queue of all the other applicants. That suggests narcissism and selfishness, which are not traits likely to help your chances of being hired for that position.
I know hiring is terrible from both sides of the table. I know it's hard to get work at the moment. I know how depressing it is to find a job posting and feel like you're the exact fit and then see that you've got hundreds of other candidates to compete against. I'm not going to tell you to trust the process, or trust in your skills, but I am going to ask you to think of the person on the other end of your unsolicited communication.

I've been told by a number of people, and also by sources online, that (especially in the current market) it can be highly beneficial to cold-write to someone (whether by e-mail or via LinkedIn) at a company after turning in a job application. The career website for my university, for instance, says "After turning in an application, you should reach out to someone at the company: a recruiter, ....", and then outlines a very similar message to what I described. There seems to be a lot of conflicting advice regarding this, however.

Extended my answer.

I think it is important to start with (whether reaching out by phone or by email) something like "I apologize if this is the wrong channel and if so I would greatly appreciate if you could point me in the right direction." With e-mail that could have unexpected spin-offs: suppose you are in charge of recruitment, then a colleague from within the company forwards you an e-mail "hey this person asked me if we had any free positions but that sounds more like your table". You are going to look at it simply because it came from a colleague, where you might have ignored it otherwise.

"Do you like getting unsolicited phone calls and spam emails?" Is an inadequate comparison. The company has already advertised they are looking for X. You're not calling them out of the blue and try to sell them an unrelated product.

The company is not one single entity. The person you decide to reach out to is likely to not be involved in the hiring process at all, or at least has no control over the stage of screening where this question is relevant. To such a person receiving the message it is in fact unsolicited spam.

@IntegerEuler The important bit from your quote might be "a recruiter". If it all, then yeah, the person handling the recruitment would be the right place, but that means you need to safely identify them. A random engineer typically will just be annoyed and at best forward the mail to someone more fitting - unless the company is so small that everyone is involved in everything basically. Even so, if I were the recruiter I'd also react negatively, cause wtf is someone thinking they will achieve with sending reaching out right after they just submitted their application - was it incomplete?

@IntegerEuler was something unclear? if there is no concrete intention associated with that request it will just waste my time. That should give you a hint on when it could be appropriate to contact: If the process and what will follow is unclear and you need to know, if you forgot something (better not to forget it in the first place though) or if the recruitment process didn't allow you to express something (e.g. just a fixed online cv form, but you want to bring something specific up) or if some time has passed and you didn't hear back.

@FrankHopkins Not at all. Thanks tremendously for the advice.

To answer the headline question:
Nothing ventured, Nothing gained
I have gotten my foot in the door and onto an Interview shortlist by stalking a company, finding a phone number of email address, contacting someone and being able to speak to a Human Being.
And so yes, I would recommend doing it. Generally you want to target the lowest rung person who has hiring and firing authority - So, a Senior Engineer or head of Engineering or a CTO.
In your example, I would probably reach out to the CEO. Failing that though, I would have a look at the company website to see if it lists any other names that you could potentially contact.
In terms of Message - Pretty much what you suggested - Who are you, what your skills are and why you are the best option.

I don't understand the DVs to this answer. I am the only business owner that has hired someone that has taken the time to do real homework?

Not my vote, but I think there's a difference between when there is an explicit job ad out (as in this case) and just reaching out to a company showing your interest. Bothering people about an advertised job by not going through the official channel is just going to rub them the wrong way. But just generally expressing your interest in the company and telling you what you are good at could be well-received.

@Lundin - that is one view, however if the company is in the sort of start-up phase that it sounds like, then I doubt they would see it as bothering. IMO Start-up types tend to value that sort of additional initiative.

@TheDemonLord that's a good point you might include. Your answer already is less a direct yes, no answer to the question and more a howto to pick the best target where this could fit. I.e. If a company is looking for particularly enthusiastic people that buy into their goal ( e.g. ngos,startups,gaming industry) it is more likely some level will see an additional reach out as a positive trait. Though I'd argue also more likely on the managerial level. And imho with the caveat that this can also be a sign for a predatory environment (who goes above and beyond, can also easier be exploited^^)

I've got a job before by applying to it and then, finding who would be my boss in a chat/slack/whatever channel asking question, I proceed to help him out. After that I asked about the company, how it was working there, and so on. And then I said I saw an opening and thought on applying for it.
TL/DR: I did something similar but without being aggressive

Sometimes.
One of the golden rules of communication is to bring value to both parties. Are you bringing value to the person you're reaching out to? That depends:

Are you interested in working at this company, or will any similar company do? If it's the latter, No - you'll get better reach by applying to a hundred companies the usual way.

You're certain the company needs this position, for instance someone has mentioned it, but there's no job ad: Definitely Yes. Creating a job posting takes time, effort, and money. By applying in advance, you might just have saved your hiring manager the effort.

This position has been posted on LinkedIn: Hard NO. This specifically means they want to use LinkedIn's recruitment interface, so you're complicating their hiring process.

You've applied outside of LinkedIn, and weren't contacted: Maybe. If you're really a strong fit for the role, maybe your resume just didn't stand out - most have too much sand to see the gold. Condense it down to one sentence, like "I've built search for AskJeeves and would like to do the same for you".

You're a unique professional that might help that company's specific needs, but they might not even realize people like you exist: Perhaps. What do you have to lose, anyway?


I have hired people who have reached out to me after having been passed over by HR, or even outright rejected by the hiring manager. Some of them have become excellent high-performers. But this mostly involves less-rewarding roles, where motivation makes the most difference. A support engineer who wants to do 12-hour night shifts will do better than one who's only in it for a pay bump.
If you do reach out personally, the quality of communication is crucial. Being brief, honest, and direct usually works best.
This works best with startups, which place a premium on motivation and willingness to take the risks associated with working at one. By reaching out, you show that you're ready for a rough ride that it can be. Large companies like FAANG receive up to a thousand of applications per position and will at best redirect you to their official job portal.
Keep in mind that they might collect on this premium: you'll have less negotiating power, and you might be expected to put in more effort in your first months, compared to someone they've had to track down and convince to join. That's why it's important that your motivation and interest in that specific company are genuine.
